# incorrect output for program reading characters

Tags: c

When the user inputs a sentence with ECE in it, the program should output ECE found!, but when ECE is the only input the program does not detect it.
I believe that all of the other cases work.

I can not use arrays or strings for this program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char input;
    char char1, char2, char3;
    printf("Please enter a sentance: ");
    scanf(" %c, %c, %c", &char1, &char2, &char3);

    while(1){
        if (char1 == 'E' && char2 == 'C' && char3 == 'E')
            printf("Found ECE!");
        if(char1 == '.' || char2 == '.'|| char3 == '.')
            break;

        scanf(" %c", &input);

        if (input == '.')
            break;

        char1 = char2;
        char2 = char3;
        char3 = input;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't enter a sentence with that format string. It has to be just 3 characters separated by commas.

Comment: Read a full string with `fgets`, then process it.

Comment: "I can not use arrays or strings for this program." -> note  that `"Please enter a sentance: "` is an _array_ and a _string_ as is `" %c, %c, %c"`.  I  suspect your limitation has exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put commas in between the `%c %c %c`. They are not needed.

`Scanf()` does something weird with characters in the `%c` area.

Comment: It's not "weird", it just matches them literally in the input.